# How can I use KaTeX in React project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, katex

How can KaTex be used in a React project? I read through documentation on NPM and still don't get it.

I don't quite see how `katex.render` and `katex.renderToString` can be applied to React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`katex.render` needs a DOM element to render in, you can get one with [a `useRef` hook](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useref-guide/#2-accessing-dom-elements).

```
const KaTeXComponent = ({texExpression}) => {
    const containerRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        katex.render(texExpression, containerRef.current);
    }, [texExpression]);

    return <div ref={containerRef} />
}
```

Comment: How do I use this snippet in a Typescript project? I'm not managing to  get around the compiler nagging for the types...

Would be so kind as to add types?

Comment: just `npm i @types/katex`

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified version of @Quentin code for React with TypeScript:

```
import katex from "katex";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "katex/dist/katex.min.css";

function KaTeX({ texExpression, className }: { texExpression: string, className: string }) {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    katex.render(texExpression, containerRef.current as HTMLInputElement);
  }, [texExpression]);

  return <div ref={containerRef} className={className} />;
}

export default KaTeX;
```

And this is what you need for installation `npm i katex @types/katex`.